# In mobile UX, which is better more taps but doesn't require thinking or lesser taps but requires a little bit of familiarization?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, usability-testing

**In mobile UX** which is better:
(a) one that requires more taps but has fewer options to consider at each level or,
(b) a UX that is broken into more categories but requires fewer taps to get to the bottom?

The app, by the way, is to be used by professionals on a daily basis — mostly male from 25 years old to 50 years old.

Comment: There are way too many variables in this question to provide a valuable answer.

Comment: @plainclothes - at this level of detail it is in fact (c) one that is built upon learning from Users on the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you provided a little bit more of details to understand the trade-off between taps (number) VS categories (complexity).
1. how many taps are required for a. (how many taps are too many taps)
2. into how many categories is b broken down into. (remember our short term memory can hold up to 7 plus/minus 2 chunks of info at a time)

Overall For UX you should consider the main design principles based on the type of user (tech expertise level: low, medium, high) you will have. Initially I would recommend a) which relies more on recognition rather than recall, but on the other hand if your users will be using the app daily they will probably build habits so maybe b) would be better for your situation. (If it is an action they will be doing very often less taps might be better)

You could always do A/B testing to see which option takes more time to complete.

Comment: The expertise level of the users is medium since they have their own smartphones and are constantly using those for social media. Required taps so far are not more than 8 at this moment for android and at the same time on iOS it only requires 5 to achieve the desired result. For first time users, most respondents who need help from that area of the app are from iOS but after being answered they feel relieved and did not asked again. I like the answer "If it is an action they will be doing very often less taps might be better" since users will be using it daily and require speed in execution.

Comment: and what about the number of categories on the second option you mentioned?